# AS3: How can I construct this Linkage problem?

Tags: actionscript-3

I want to do something like this with AS3, but I'm new to AS3 and I'm not sure how to go about the coding.

What I need to do is I have 1 x blank MC called `all_mc`, inside that I need to have 200 x `empty_mc` all lined up one after another on the x axis.

Each `empty_mc` is 100px wide and load from a Linkage in the library called `panelClass` (which is a MovieClip).

The `empty_mc` itself is called `emptyClass` in the library.

I need the `all_mc` to display on the stage from start. [It should look like this image.](http://img694.imageshack.us/img694/6774/squaresep.jpg) The I need 200 of these red squares.

I know instead of adding all 200 MCs manually, I should be making a loop? But I can not get my head around it for the life of me. Can someone please kindly help me out?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just make a loop and dynamically create your MovieClips:

```
var mcWidth:Number = 100; // Using hardcoded value because MovieClip.width is not always reliable (if the MovieClip contains shapes with strokes, etc.)
for (var i:int = 0; i < 200; i++) {
    var mc:panelClass = new panelClass();
    all_mc.addChild(mc);
    mc.name = "empty_mc" + i; // set a name so that it can be accessed later on 
    mc.x = mcWidth * i;
}
```

Comment: Thanks Laurent, I actually need all the empty_mc's inside all_mc

Comment: Then just change the `addChild` line to `all_mc.addChild(mc);` (post edited)